# Expect argument handling

Tags: tcl, expect, arguments

I'd like to create an expect script that connects to the server via telnet and does some authorisation. I have a problem with using script parameters though. Based on man I expected this to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet $argv1 5038
...
```

Unfortunately I get back `can't read "argv1": no such variable`. How can make this work?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this at serverfault.com

Comment: Why? It's a question about expect / tcl programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$argv` is a Tcl list holding the command line parameters, indexed beginning from 0. You want:

```
[lindex $argv 0]
```

Comment: You won by 2 minutes :) Thanks. There's an example in man that mentions $argv0, which is what confused me.

Comment: so was i (confused by this example)

Answer (score 5):

Commmand line arguments are provided as a list in variable argv, you can use lindex to get an element from this list, so if the first argument is the host to telnet to, do:

```
spawn telnet [lindex $argv 0] 5038
```

See **Shell Provided Variables** in [Shells](http://home.comcast.net/~brian199/tcl_tk_ref_guide.html#Shells) and **lindex** in [Lists](http://home.comcast.net/~brian199/tcl_tk_ref_guide.html#Lists)

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error, `can't read "argv0": no such variable`, when I tried to use $argv0 in a proc. The solution was to explicitly access it from the global namespace by using `$::argv0`.